# How to count items in a Go map?

Tags: dictionary, go

If I want to count the items in the map structure, what statement should I use?
I tried to use

```
for _, _ := range m {...}
```

but it seems the syntax is false.

Comment: Slightly off topic, you can also use `for _ := range m {}`, no need for two arguments there.

Comment: BTW, both `for _, _ := range m {...}` and `for _ := range m {}` will not compile b/c of the `:=`, which cannot be used w/ `_` only LHSs. `=` must be used in this cases instead.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use `len(m)`. From http://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity

```
len(s)    string type      string length in bytes
          [n]T, *[n]T      array length (== n)
          []T              slice length
          map[K]T          map length (number of defined keys)
          chan T           number of elements queued in channel buffer
```

Here are a couple examples ported from the now-retired SO documentation:

```
m := map[string]int{}
len(m) // 0

m["foo"] = 1
len(m) // 1
```

If a variable points to a `nil` map, then `len` returns 0.

```
var m map[string]int
len(m) // 0
```

> Excerpted from [Maps - Counting map elements](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006194004/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/go/732/maps/2528/counting-map-elements). The original author was [Simone Carletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/2528). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 732 and example ID: 2528.

Comment: What about if it's a `map[string][]` & I want to count the total # of elements?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone wanting to count the number of elements in a nested map:

```golang
  var count int
  m := map[string][]int{}
  for _, t := range m {
    count += len(t)
  }
```